# Tracking MySQL DML Operations Source

Tags: mysql, audit

We have a table that will get inserts and updates from 10 different jobs. We need to track each DML operation with its source i.e job name. We have used audit tables and triggers to get old and new table data but we are not able to track the job which is responsible for that DML operation.

is it possible to track DML operation source?

Comment: what kind of jobs are you trying to track? the exact SQL query perhaps? can you be more specific?